# Need to set unknown amount of datasets together

Tags: sas, dataset

I have a macro that creates multiple datasets. The number of datasets depends on other factors and could be 0-X. I need to set all of these datasets together into one dataset to export.

```
%macro runpromo(setid=, title=, start=, end=, no=);

%get_offer_data(label=&title , start=date &start, end=date &end, rc=%quote(&setid), source=1);

data promo&no.;
length item_desc $50.0;
set edw_final;
run;

%mend runpromo;
data _null_;
set macros;
call execute('%runpromo(setid='||code||',title='||promo_title||',start ='||start_date||',end='||end_date||',no='||count||');');
run;


data all_promos;
length item_desc $50.0;
set promo1-promoX;
run;
```

I want to automate this code to run daily so I don't want to have to go in and update the dataset names each time.

Comment: Can you modify the macro to append the datasets as they are created?  Do you even need to keep the individual datasets if you want the full dataset?

Answer (score 3):

Use a naming convention where each data set has the same prefix and goes to a single library. Then you can stack them easily at the end:

```
data want;
   set prom:;
run;
```

The colon (`:`) acts as a wild card and all datasets with the prefix prom in the work library will be combined.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just build the larger dataset as you go?

Macro Definition:

```
%macro runpromo(setid=, title=, start=, end=, no=);

%get_offer_data(label=&title,start=date &start,end=date &end,rc=%quote(&setid),source=1);

data promo_fix;
  length item_desc $50;
  set edw_final;
run;

proc append base=all_promos data=promo_fix force;
run;

%mend runpromo;
```

Program:

```
proc delete data=all_promos;
run;

data _null_;
  set macros;
  call execute(cats('%nrstr(%runpromo)'
              ,'(setid=',code
              ,',title=',promo_title
              ,',start =',start_date
              ,',end=',end_date
              ,',no=',count
              ,');'
   ));
run;
```